# touchstart event does not trigger on scrollable div if already scrolling (on iPhone)

Tags: web, scroll, mobile-safari, touch-event, touchstart

I have met this problem when scrolling on my iPhone 6 device (tested on Safari and Chrome):

Given a scrollable div, if i touch the div when it's already on inertial scrolling motion, the scrolling motion stops as expected but the `touchstart` event does not trigger at all.

When tested on Xiaomi Android device (tested on Chrome) the scroll stops **AND** the `touchstart` event is fired.

Why is `touchstart` not triggered?. Is it a standard behaviour on iPhone?.

I have set up a fiddle to test this behaviour:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/galoxia/L63wj9or/

Just make the gesture to "activate" inertial scrolling on the blue box and then touch again to stop it. On Android you will see `touchstart` in the yellow box. On iPhone you will not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this same problem while trying to implement a double-tap handler for touch devices in JavaScript. If a momentum scroll is happening in iOS Safari, then `touchstart` events aren't sent for approximately 500 ms after the initial `touchstart` (the `touchstart` that initiated the scroll).

If you put a `preventDefault()` in the `touchstart` handler, then this solves the issue (but disables scrolling). That might be an acceptable solution depending on your use case. As I see it, the two possible options are:

1. Disable "native scrolling via touch" and receive all `touchstart` events (use `preventDefault()` in the `touchstart` handler)
2. Enable "native scrolling via touch" but do not receive `touchstart` events for approximately 500 ms after the initial `touchstart` in a scroll

I'd love to be proven wrong on this. If there's a way to consistently get `touchstart` events without calling `preventDefault()` in the `touchstart` handler and without breaking native scroll, please post a comment here.